# [CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]

Tags: java, playframework

I tried to add some mappings to my Administrator.java class and that start to give me errors for when I clicked the login button, regardless of what user is logging in or if the credentials are correct or not. Prior to adding the extra functionality everything worked fine.

Stack Trace:

```
[error] o.j.ConnectionLogger - java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement:
throws exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Ambiguous column name "ID"; SQL statement:
select t0.role c0, t0.email c1, t0.role c2, t0.name c3, t0.password c4, t1.id c5, t0.department c6, t0.street1 c7, t0.street2 c8, t0.town c9, t0.post_code c10, t1.id c11, t2.id c12 from user t0 left outer join stock_basket t1 on t1.administrator_email = t0.email  left outer join basket t1 on t1.customer_email = t0.email  left outer join credit_card t2 on t2.customer_email = t0.email  where t0.email = ?  and t0.password = ?  [90059-191]
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Ambiguous column name "ID"; SQL statement:
select t0.role c0, t0.email c1, t0.role c2, t0.name c3, t0.password c4, t1.id c5, t0.department c6, t0.street1 c7, t0.street2 c8, t0.town c9, t0.post_code c10, t1.id c11, t2.id c12 from user t0 left outer join stock_basket t1 on t1.administrator_email = t0.email  left outer join basket t1 on t1.customer_email = t0.email  left outer join credit_card t2 on t2.customer_email = t0.email  where t0.email = ?  and t0.password = ?  [90059-191]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.mapColumn(ExpressionColumn.java:124)
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.mapColumns(ExpressionColumn.java:94)
        at org.h2.expression.Alias.mapColumns(Alias.java:46)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.mapColumns(Select.java:1228)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.init(Select.java:827)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1693)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:443)
[error] application -

! @73gmcki3k - Internal server error, for (POST) [/login] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
        at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
        at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
        at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
        at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:21)
        at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:18)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at play.data.Form.bind(Form.java:425)
        at play.data.Form.bindFromRequest(Form.java:234)
        at controllers.security.LoginCtrl.loginSubmit(LoginCtrl.java:35)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Routes.scala:900)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Routes.scala:900)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:157)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:156)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:136)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:73)
        at play.http.HttpRequestHandler$1.call(HttpRequestHandler.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at play.data.Form.bind(Form.java:421)
        at play.data.Form.bindFromRequest(Form.java:234)
        at controllers.security.LoginCtrl.loginSubmit(LoginCtrl.java:35)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Routes.scala:900)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Routes.scala:900)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:157)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Ambiguous column name "ID"; SQL statement:
select t0.role c0, t0.email c1, t0.role c2, t0.name c3, t0.password c4, t1.id c5, t0.department c6, t0.street1 c7, t0.street2 c8, t0.town c9, t0.post_code c10, t1.id c11, t2.id c12 from user t0 left outer join stock_basket t1 on t1.administrator_email = t0.email  left outer join basket t1 on t1.customer_email = t0.email  left outer join credit_card t2 on t2.customer_email = t0.email  where t0.email = ?  and t0.password = ?  [90059-191]
Bind values:[null]
Query was:
select t0.role c0, t0.email c1, t0.role c2, t0.name c3, t0.password c4, t1.id c5, t0.department c6, t0.street1 c7, t0.street2 c8, t0.town c9, t0.post_code c10, t1.id c11, t2.id c12 from user t0 left outer join stock_basket t1 on t1.administrator_email = t0.email  left outer join basket t1 on t1.customer_email = t0.email  left outer join credit_card t2 on t2.customer_email = t0.email  where t0.email = ?  and t0.password = ?


        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQuery.createPersistenceException(CQuery.java:673)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQuery.createPersistenceException(CQuery.java:653)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQueryEngine.findMany(CQueryEngine.java:324)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.DefaultOrmQueryEngine.findMany(DefaultOrmQueryEngine.java:94)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.OrmQueryRequest.findList(OrmQueryRequest.java:347)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.findList(DefaultServer.java:1388)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.findUnique(DefaultServer.java:1138)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.querydefn.DefaultOrmQuery.findUnique(DefaultOrmQuery.java:1104)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.expression.DefaultExpressionList.findUnique(DefaultExpressionList.java:352)
        at models.users.User.authenticate(User.java:60)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Ambiguous column name "ID"; SQL statement:
select t0.role c0, t0.email c1, t0.role c2, t0.name c3, t0.password c4, t1.id c5, t0.department c6, t0.street1 c7, t0.street2 c8, t0.town c9, t0.post_code c10, t1.id c11, t2.id c12 from user t0 left outer join stock_basket t1 on t1.administrator_email = t0.email  left outer join basket t1 on t1.customer_email = t0.email  left outer join credit_card t2 on t2.customer_email = t0.email  where t0.email = ?  and t0.password = ?  [90059-191]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.mapColumn(ExpressionColumn.java:124)
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.mapColumns(ExpressionColumn.java:94)
        at org.h2.expression.Alias.mapColumns(Alias.java:46)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.mapColumns(Select.java:1228)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.init(Select.java:827)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1693)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:443)
```

User class:

```
package models.users;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.data.format.*;
import play.data.validation.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.*;

//https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGuide4

// Product entity managed by Ebean
@Entity
// specify mapped table name
@Table(name = "user")
// Map inherited classes to a single table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) 
// Discriminator column used to define user type
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "role")
// This user type is user
@DiscriminatorValue("user") 

public class User extends Model {

    //@Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    //public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Id
    private String email;

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String role;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String name;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String password;


    // Default constructor
    public  User() {
    }
    // Constructor to initialise object
    public User(String email, String role, String name, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.role = role;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    //Generic query helper for entity User with unique id String
    public static Finder<String,User> find = new Finder<String,User>(User.class);

    // Static method to authenticate based on username and password
    // Returns user object if found, otherwise NULL
    public static User authenticate(String email, String password) {
        // If found return the user object with matching username and password
        return find.where().eq("email", email).eq("password", password).findUnique();
    }

    // Check if a user is logged in (by id - email address)
    public static User getLoggedIn(String id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            // Find user by id and return object
            return find.byId(id);
        }
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Admin class:

```
package models.users;

import models.products.Category;
import models.products.Review;
import models.shopping.Basket;
import models.shopping.ShopOrder;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import models.stock.StockBasket;
import models.stock.StockOrder;
import play.data.validation.*;

@Entity
// This is a User of type admin
@DiscriminatorValue("admin")

// Administrator inherits from the User class
public class Administrator extends User {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "administrator", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private StockBasket basket;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "administrator", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<StockOrder> orders;

    public Administrator() {

    }

    public Administrator(String email, String role, String name, String password)
    {
        super(email, role, name, password);
    }

    public StockBasket getBasket() {
        return basket;
    }

    public void setBasket(StockBasket basket) {
        this.basket = basket;
    }

    public List<StockOrder> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<StockOrder> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave stock_basket and basket the same alias (t1) in the query.

Change one alias to t3, and this should work:

```
select t0.role c0, t0.email c1, t0.role c2, t0.name c3, t0.password c4, t1.id c5, 
    t0.department c6, t0.street1 c7, t0.street2 c8, t0.town c9, t0.post_code c10, t3.id c11, t2.id c12 
from user t0 
left outer join stock_basket t1 on t1.administrator_email = t0.email  
left outer join basket t3 on t3.customer_email = t0.email  
left outer join credit_card t2 on t2.customer_email = t0.email
```

This is one of the reasons it's easier to use aliases that can be identified back to the table names instead of t1, t2, etc.